# SQLite subquery

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, subquery

I have a query with a subquery that returns multiple rows.

I have a table with lists and a table with users. I created a many-to-many table between these two tables, called list_user.

```
LIST
id INTEGER
list_name TEXT
list_description TEXT

USER
id INTEGER
user_name TEXT

LIST_USER
id INTEGER
list_id INTEGER
user_id INTEGER
```

My query with subquery

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = (SELECT user_id FROM list_user WHERE list_id = 0);
```

The subquery works (and I use it in code so the 0 is actually a variable) and it returns multiple rows. But the upper query only returns one row, which is pretty logical; I check if the id equals something and it only checks against the first row of the subquery.

How do I change my statement so I get multiple rows in the upper query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm surprised the `=` works in SQLite.  It would return an error in most databases.  In any case, you want the `in` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE id in (SELECT user_id FROM list_user WHERE list_id = 0);
```

Comment: Actually, while it does improve the query (tried it in SQLite browser) my code still returns only 1 row. My query SELECT * FROM person WHERE id IN(SELECT user_id FROM list_user WHERE user_id=2); returns 1 row. SELECT user_id FROM list_user WHERE user_id=2; (the subquery) returns 2 rows. I just printed it... Why is it doing that?

Comment: Do the two rows have the same user_id ?

Comment: No, they have user_id 1 and user_id 2 in this case.

Comment: ... I fixed it. I have WHERE user_id = x, and I should have WHERE list_id = x.

Answer (score 2):

For a better performance, use this query:

```
SELECT LIST.ID,
       LIST.LIST_NAME,
       LIST.LIST_DESCRIPTION 
FROM   LIST,
       USER,
       LIST_USER
WHERE  LIST.ID = LIST_USER.USER_ID = USER.ID AND
       LIST.LIST_ID = 0
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this simply because it does not use proper join syntax.  Could you explain why this would have better performance?